# Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2apim-analytics-service.domain.com:7712

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up a multi-region WSO2 APIM environment. The gateway component in the slave region is failing to connect with the API Analytics component in the Master region with the following error:

```
[2019-09-02 09:24:02,563] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2apim-analytics-service.domain.com:7712.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2apim-analytics-service.domain.com:7712.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:134)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:128)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.send_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:95)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:47)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:750)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:159)
```

Analytics is already enabled in the slave region. Also, we are able to telnet on port 7712 to the analytics service in the master region.

Why is the "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of points that you should check.

1. Domain resolution on the slave region.
2. Check the connection from the slave to the master , firewall rules , etc.
3. Check the certificate on both sides and that it match with the domain name.

Use `openssl s_client -connect wso2apim-analytics-service.domain.com:7712`

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!. Openssl does seem to be working. However, I want to see more details in the logs specifically for the analytics components. How can I enable the debug levels of the analytics to see more details?

Comment: Nodeport setup for the 7712 port was not correct. Changing it to the right port fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once the debug logs are enabled for below class, when graphs are selected for analytics, it will log the Siddhi queries it sends to the analytics server.
This would help us to capture exact queries publisher portal sends to the analytics server and try to identify any culprit points available.

1. Shutdown the server.
2. Add the following property to /repository/conf/log4j.properties
   *log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil=DEBUG*
3. Restart the server

Please refer to [1] for more details on logging.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Setting+Up+Logging

Comment: Can you also point to the property files that needs to be updated to enable debug logging on the analytics server? Analytics server follows a different setup altogether.

Comment: For APIM Analytics 2.6.0 you van refer to [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Configuring+Carbon+Logs otherwise please refer to [2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Logging.